# Removing a file called ~

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I accidentally named a file `~` when I was trying to move it to my home directory.  And now in my `/` there is a file called `~` and I have no idea how I would remove it.

How would I remove a file that I accidentally renamed `~`?

Comment: @black IMHO it is *on-topic* since it is about shell programming.

Comment: @hek2mgl I don't see how it could be about shell programming.

Comment: @black Let's agree that it is an edge-case. Understanding how the `~` get's expanded by bash *is* related to bash programming, while the use case "removing files which have been created by accident" is more related to sysadmin work. However, this is quite common in the shell related tags since the shell is used by sysadmins, either interactive or in a script.

Comment: @NisseEngström Valid point. I've tagged it *bash*.

Comment: @hek2mgl No, it's related to _bash_ and how a shell works in general (which is OT). If this issue was met say in a script then it'd be okay.

Comment: `rm \~`, `rm ./~`, `rm '~'`, `rm "~"`. Note that unlike one of the solutions for a file named `-`, the command `rm -- ~` will *not* work; `~` is expanded by the shell before `rm` sees it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the filename in quotes:

```
rm '~'
```

You can follow the `bash` manual:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html

> If a word begins with an **unquoted** tilde character (‘~’), all of the characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix. ...

Comment: I should have thought of that!  I will accept this answer as correct, asap.

Thanks!

Comment: It gives `rm: cannot remove ‘~’: Is a directory`

Comment: To remove a directory you need to use `rm -r '~'`

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a backslash to remove it.

```
 rm \~
```

Comment: It gives `rm: cannot remove ‘~’: Is a directory`